# I can't move two paddles at the same time in pong game I am making

Tags: java, processing

So I am trying to code pong in processing and everything is working fine, and I can move the paddles up and down perfectly, however, when you try to move two paddles at the same time, they don't move / it doesn't let you (I am going to make this a 2 player game so that 2 people can play using the same keyboard but with different keys for the different paddles).

I believe this is an issue with using "key" or "keyPressed", because I think it can't detect both or something? but I can't seem to figure out how to fix this or any alternatives. (Keep in mind that I know how to move the paddles, its just that you can't move them both at the same time with the different provided keys like im trying to)

I have two objects so far, "Player1" and "Player2"

keep in mind "y" is the y position which will either go up or down depending on the key pressed, and "speed" is just the speed that the paddle will move.

This is in Player1. Up = w, Down = s

```
void movement() {

    if(keyPressed) {

      if(key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
        y = y - speed; //goes up

      } else if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
        y = y + speed; //goes down
      }
    }
  }
```

This is in Player2. Up = up arrow key, Down = down arrow key

```
void movement() {

    if (keyPressed) {

      if(key == CODED) {

      if(keyCode == UP) {
        y = y - speed; //goes up

      } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        y = y + speed; //goes down
      }

    }

    }

  }
```

No error messages, just doesn't let you move 2 paddles at the same time, which is something I'd like to do.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input#handling-multiple-keys) is a tutorial on handling multiple key presses in Processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've to use the [`keyPressed`](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html) and [`keyReleased()`](https://processing.org/reference/keyReleased_.html) events. The events are executed once when a key is pressed or released.
Set a state when a key is pressed, respectively reset the state when the key is released:

```java
Boolean player1_up = false;
Boolean player1_down = false;
Boolean player2_up = false;
Boolean player2_down = false;

void keyPressed() {
    if (keyCode == UP)
        player1_up = true;
    else if (keyCode == DOWN)
        player1_up = true;
    if (key == 'w' || key == 'W')
        player2_up = true;
    else if (key == 's' || key == 'S')
        player2_down = true;
}

void keyReleasd() {
    if (keyCode == UP)
        player1_up = false;
    else if (keyCode == DOWN)
        player1_up = false;
    if (key == 'w' || key == 'W')
        player2_up = false;
    else if (key == 's' || key == 'S')
        player2_down = false;
}
```

Use the states `player1_up`, `player1_down`, `player2_up` and `player2_down` in the `movement` functions.